# Parsing time via regex for voice activated alarm

Tags: regex, voice-recognition

I'm trying to write a regex expression that can properly parse as many of these possible verbal commands to set an alarm e.g.:

Group 1:

> set an alarm at 3:50 p.m.
>     set an alarm for tomorrow at 3:50
>     set an alarm for 6 a.m.
>     set an alarm for 3 o'clock

Group 2:

> set an alarm in 1 hour 10 minutes
>     set an alarm in 59 minutes
>     set an alarm in 6 hours

Group 3:

> set an alarm in 3 quarter hours from now
>     set an alarm in 2 and a half hours
>     set an alarm in half an hour

This expression works for Group 1:

```
(\D)+(\d+)(?::)?(\d+)?(?: )?(a\.m\.|p\.m\.)?(.+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/H6z5NU/3

set an alarm for tomorrow at 3 p.m.
  Group 1.  28-29   
  Group 2.  29-30   `3`
  Group 5.  31-35   `p.m.`

set an alarm for tomorrow at 3:50 p.m.
  Group 1.  28-29   
  Group 2.  29-30   `3`
  Group 3.  31-33   `50`
  Group 5.  34-38   `p.m.`

The expression works for Group 2:

```
(\D)+(\d+){1,2}( hour| minute)((\D)+(\d+){1,2}( minute))?(.+)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/3yt7tK/1

set an alarm in 20 hours and 1 minute
  Group 1.  15-16   
  Group 2.  16-18   `20`
  Group 3.  18-23   `hour`
  Group 4.  23-37   `s and 1 minute`
  Group 5.  28-29   
  Group 6.  29-30   `1`
  Group 7.  30-37   `minute`

set an alarm in 1 minute
  Group 1.  15-16   
  Group 2.  16-17   `1`
  Group 3.  17-24   `minute`

But I'm driving myself nuts trying to get the secret sauce that can handle combining the am/pm hour/minute.

Addendum:  I've got my own recognition parser built using various tools (e.g. vanilla python - no ML imports) and it already successfully handles several tasks... just trying to add an alarm setting task and hoping to get some regex help.  Thanks!

**===========  Yet another update  ===========**

This expression works for Group 1:

```
(\D+)(noon|midnight|\d{1,2})(?::(\d{0,2})| o'clock)?(?: )?(p.m.|a.m.|noon|midnight)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/H6z5NU/5

And also handles "12 noon" or "midnight"

And... this expression works well for both Group 2 and Group 3:

```
(\D)?(\d){0,2}(?: )?(and a )?(hour|minute|quarter|half)((\D)+(\d+){0,2}(?: )?(minute|hour))?(.+)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/3yt7tK/2

For now, I'll probably just use these two separately and determine the appropriate one by looking for the distinct keywords.

Comment: Less a job for regex, more a job for machine learning and AI. Which programming language?

Comment: There are folks who've done reasonably good jobs of this -- there's actually a Perl module from back in the day that's astonishingly comprehensive -- but it's not a trivial task, and indeed, not a job for which a regular expression is an ideal fit.

Comment: See [DateTime::Format::Natural](http://search.cpan.org/~schubiger/DateTime-Format-Natural-1.05/lib/DateTime/Format/Natural.pm) and, more specifically, [DateTime::Format::Natural::Lang::EN](http://search.cpan.org/~schubiger/DateTime-Format-Natural-1.05/lib/DateTime/Format/Natural/Lang/EN.pm); if nothing else, the set of test cases will be useful. [Natty](http://natty.joestelmach.com/) is another option for those of us with allergies to Perl, and since it has a formal (ANTLR) grammar specification, provides a particularly good place to start if you *really need* a regex.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thx for the interesting links.  Natty worked most of the time, but falls apart for "set an alarm for next tuesday at half past 2".  I'm avoiding any addt'l imports to my code (i.e. KISS as much as regex parsing will suffice) for my fairly simple use cases.

Comment: Personally, I'd file a ticket against Natty for the case it can't handle -- working on a project with a test suite and some rigor to its development is the right place to be if you want a robust and maintainable result.